# Function expressions can't be named: then(

Tags: flutter, dart, http

Im having issues with my code and since I'm new at using Flutter, I have no clue on how to fix it. I was trying to fix the `http.get(string)` and I kind of did, but now I'm having issues with `then(())`.

```
void submitForm(FeedbackForm feedbackForm) async {
try {
  await http.get(Uri.parse(URL + feedbackForm.toParams()).then((response)) {
    callback(convert.jsonDecode(response.body['status']));
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}
}

Comment: Describe "issues".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got a parenthesis missplaced:

```
await http.get(...).then((response) => callback(...))
```

The them allows you to use the result of the previous Future, as soon as it becomes available. If you find it confusing you can declare one variable at a time.

```
final response = await http.get(...);
// Check if response was as expected
await callback();
```